# Query, edit and add attributes in objects from Active Directory

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, vb.net-2010

I need to create a small app using visual basic that will retrieve a user from AD and edit/add some attributes. The code here queries the ldap and fills some textboxes with the info found in the object property. My vb knowledge  is limited so please understand my question, i want to know if there's are better ways to achieve this goal:

```
    Dim deSystem As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://etc")
    Dim dsSystem As New DirectorySearcher(deSystem)
    Dim srsystem As SearchResult

        Try

            dsSystem.Filter = ("(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" & TextBox1.Text & "))")
            dsSystem.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
            dsSystem.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
            dsSystem.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName")
            dsSystem.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")
            dsSystem.PropertiesToLoad.Add("proxyAddresses")

            srsystem = dsSystem.FindOne()

            TextBox2.Text = srsystem.Properties("givenName").Item(0).ToString
            TextBox3.Text = srsystem.Properties("sn").Item(0).ToString
            Button3.Enabled = True

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(TextBox1.Text & " is an Invalid UserID")
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Focus()

        End Try
```

Some of the properties contain multiple lines and some of the properties do not exist for certain object, how do I insert the multiline information in a multiline textbox for examaple, and how do I prevent the code to send an error if the attribute does not exist? For now i query the property from line 0 using ".Item(0).ToString" and if the property does not exist it return an error, i need to bypass those.
And the most important part is: how to update the attributes or add new attributes for the object in AD?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
    }

    // find the group in question
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

    // if found....
    if (group != null)
    {
       // iterate over members
       foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
           // do whatever you need to do to those members
       }
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!